# Checkbox on left of an item in NavigationView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using the design support library's NavigationView, and in the menu it uses I have included the following:

```
<item android:title="Check The CheckBox"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox"/>
```

Which solved half my problem as now I had a checkbox, however I wished to to have the CheckBox appear where usually the icon is placed, much like how it is done in the Google Calendar app with the list of calendars

Answer (score 0):

Menu items have a `checkable` attribute.

```
<item android:title="Check The CheckBox"
    android:checkable="true"/>
```

You can also `<group>` several checkable items together.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="all">
    <item android:title="Check The CheckBox"/>
</group>
```

Comment: This does not add a CheckBox to menu items when the menu is in a NavigationView.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your CheckBox appear on the left of your menu items your best bet is to set the icon of your menu items as a checked or unchecked image (depending on the checked state of your menu items). I've just had a look at the Google Calendar app and this is what it appears to be doing. Also, the Android [Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) documentation alludes to this:

> Note: Menu items in the Icon Menu (from the options menu) cannot
>   display a checkbox or radio button. If you choose to make items in the
>   Icon Menu checkable, you must manually indicate the checked state by
>   swapping the icon and/or text each time the state changes.